# Why do we use SimpleLoadTimeWeaver?

Tags: java, spring

I see code some where using "Simple Load Timer Weaver" while declaring entityManager bean in spring xml file as below:

```
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:./META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testDB" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Iam not able to identify the purpose of class SimpleLoadTimeWeaver in this? Could any body let me know the pros & cons of using the class over here.**

Comment: Do you know what a weaver in general is? Are you familiar with AOP?

Comment: read the doc, it says "Mainly intended for testing environments, where it is sufficient to perform all class transformation on a newly created ClassLoader instance.

Comment: @Depeng : I read the doc already but not able to exactly understand the class purpose though?

Comment: @Thomas: I have no idea what a waver is.I have just taken up that code from some net and used in my app.So that's my question what exactly a weaver is?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify what a *weaver* is:

With AOP you define logic that is invoked at defined points in your code, e.g. whenever a setter is called. Since that logic is developed outside the classes you want to decorate this way (you don't want to put that logic into *all* setters yourself) the runtime needs a means to know that this should be executed.

Thus at some point in time (either compile time or load time) the AOP logic is added to all points in your code that it applies to and class proxies are generated (and compiled). This process is called weaving since your original code and the AOP logic you defined are woven together.

For more information on Spring AOP, have a look here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

Answer (score 0):

From [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/instrument/classloading/SimpleLoadTimeWeaver.html)

> LoadTimeWeaver that builds and exposes a
>   SimpleInstrumentableClassLoader.
>
> Mainly intended for testing environments, where it is sufficient to
>   perform all class transformation on a newly created ClassLoader
>   instance.

And from `SimpleInstrumentableClassLoader` [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/instrument/classloading/SimpleInstrumentableClassLoader.html)

> Simplistic implementation of an instrumentable ClassLoader.
>
> Usable in tests and standalone environments.

Comment: Hi,Could you explain me what is the purpose of using this class as i don't understand the clear picture what the doc says.